# How to do non-buffered writes to stdout?

Tags: windows, rust

I need 20 'H' characters to appear at 1 second intervals. This program displays nothing till the end

```rust
use std::io::Write;
use std::time::Duration;
fn main() {
    let ch = 'H' as u8;
    for _ in 0..20 {
        let buff = vec![ch];
        std::io::stdout().write(&buff).unwrap();
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
    }
}
```

This equivalent C++ program works fine

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        std::cout << (char)'H';
        std::cout.flush();
        Sleep(1000); 
    }
}
```

I tried crossterm and could not make that work but it looks really interesting. I tried crossterm_winapi which has direct calls to `WriteConsoleW` in it, but then I got no output at all.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM they're specifically talking about windows and crossterm_winapi so probably not.

Comment: You can directly use byte array literals instead of vec: `stdout().write(b"H")`

Comment: It works properly on my windows btw

Comment: The C++ program is definitely *not* equivalent. I’m actually surprised it works for you at all, since stdout is by default line buffered, and you don’t flush. Maybe whatever console you’re using on Windows has a different behaviour but this isn’t guaranteed (and the `(char)` cast is weird and unnecessary).

Comment: I'm new to Rust, but do you need `unwrap()`? There's no return value and you don't assign a variable.

Comment: @ThomasWeller it returns `Result` and `unwrap` does panic the program(closes process with an error code) if result is an `Error`. `unwrap` is not a good way to handle error but most of the time  it is useful to create quick examples or POCs.)

Comment: @ThomasWeller In addition to Ömer’s comment, it’s important to note that in Rust you shouldn’t ignore `Result` return values; to do so causes a compiler warning: Rust *forces* you to handle `Result`s (because otherwise you’d be silently swallowing errors, which is bad), which is done here by simply `unwrap`ing it.

Comment: Consider using [Term::stdout](https://docs.rs/console/0.12.0/console/struct.Term.html#method.stdout) or roll your own if you really have to, because rust std just pulls out the default stdout without changing any settings (nor allowing you to either) which is usually line buffered.

Comment: @KonradRudolph nothing weird going on here, type the code into vs2019, hit f5

Comment: @pm100 Just because it happens works when run inside a debug console (which is what happens in VS when hitting F5) doesn’t mean it will work when run in a “real” terminal. In particular, VS probably doesn’t buffer the standard streams because it’s convenient. By contrast, it definitely doesn’t work for me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph well , i just ran it from windows console directly , no debugger, nothing and it behaves the same. Try it. Release build.

Comment: @pm100 I’m a bit surprised but it’s not impossible. All I’m saying is that you can’t *rely* on that behaviour; you *must* manually flush the output stream to get reliable behaviour. (I can’t try it because I can currently only run Windows in a KVM or via Wine, where, as mentioned, this *doesn’t* work).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - ok I changed the c++ code. So that has a flush in it (it does the same thing but it will hopefully stop people getting sidetracked).

Comment: @Yamuri make that answer please. Interesing that run inside vscode debugger the whole line is buffered, but run outside the debugger it behaves as expected.

Comment: @ÖmerErden in my real case I have a single u8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question because I went through a lot of discovery here and I am sure other will find it useful.

BTW - the original question got derailed in the comments section explaining why my c++ equivalent (without flush) worked / didnt work / shouldnt work / might work. Lets ignore that - I added flush.

**Firstly Debuggers**

vscode and Vs2019 do stuff with stdout in order to try to be helpful. Most of the time it is helpful but not in this case

vscode steals stdout to make it appear in the terminal window. Normally this would be directed to a console window. It also imposes its own buffering regardless of what you do with flushing etc.

The real end for my rust code is a c# gui application calling the rust code as a cdylib. Originally this dll was written in c++. When running a GUI app vs2019 also steals stdout (not the case for console apps, nothing to do with my mini c++ code above) so that it can display it the 'output' window.

Both these behaviors disappear if the app is run outside the debugger of course. But that makes debugging tough.

This of course confused a lot of my investigation because I was not seeing output in various cases because I was looking in the wrong place.

**Solution 1**

The original code in my question actually works fine if you run it via cargo run from a console window. Excellent. vscode buffers it all up if ran from inside it - so dont do that.

**Problem 2, no console window**

Windows gui app launch 'knows' that this program doesnt need a console window so stdout is piped to a bitbucket. I had the same issue in the c# -> c++ version. The secret here is to create a console window and reattach stdout to it.

**solution 2**

Reaches for winapi crate.

```
  unsafe {
        let ff = winapi::um::wincon::FreeConsole();
        let ret = winapi::um::consoleapi::AllocConsole();
        let err = winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError();
      };
```

FreeConsole just to detach if we are connected to something weird. Then AllocConsole creates a console window and connects the process to it, not wired up to anything yet though. So now wire the new console window to stdout:

```
let file = OpenOptions::new().write(true).read(true).open("CONOUT$").unwrap();
unsafe{
    let err = winapi::um::processenv::SetStdHandle(winapi::um::winbase::STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, file.as_raw_handle());
}
```

CONOUT$ is special name for the output buffer of the connected console window. SetStdHandle connects it to stdout.

Now a new window pops up next to the gui and all stdout writes appear there - whoo hoo.

This also works for vscode debugging. A new 'dos' window appears and the stdout appears there. An added bonus

**Problem 3 need lower level access**

In my original PDP engine in c++ I was not happy still using std::cout, I needed to get as close the the windows console subsystem as possible (I am emulating the behavior of a raw physical device for the PDP). So I decided to use direct windows IO in this new version

**Solution 3**

So still AllocConsole and open CONOUT$ but call the Console write directly

```
  let buff: [u8; 1] = [ch];
  let ptr: *const c_void = buff.as_ptr() as *const _ as *const c_void;

  let mut cells_written: u32 = 0;
  // write to console
  unsafe {
      WriteConsoleA(
          file.as_raw_handle(),
          ptr,
          1,
          &mut cells_written,
          NULL,
      ) ;
    };
```

file is the handle return by open of CONOUT$

Works nicely. I know I will need to do the same for stdin / CONIN$ at some point

Comment: Since this is being called from a C# program, it seems the easiest solution to "problem 2" would be to just change the C# project's output type in VS from "Windows Application" to "Console Application" (or `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>` to `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` if editing the `.csproj` file manually). This will build an executable that doesn't hide the console window, while still allowing you to display your UI as usual

Comment: @Herohtar - but then I wont get ouput in my vscode hosted testbed. But I will give that a shot though, just to see what happens.

Comment: You'll still get output there; VS Code just attaches to whatever output is being used.